# DataTable take too much time to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using DataTables to show the data from SQL server. When a button was clicked in the parent window, the popup with data table shows up. The popup is displayed correctly if the data is less than 1000 rows. When the data is too much (over 1000 rows), the popup never show up. The same query runs at database last 8 sec. What am I missing?

```js
function my_popup() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "../popup/getDataForPopup",
    success: function(result) {
      var data = $.parseJSON(result);
      var dataSet = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var arr = ["<input type = 'button' class='btn-primary' value = 'Select' onclick ='send_parent()' data-dismiss='modal'>",
          data[i].date,
          data[i].name,
          data[i].place,
          data[i].something +
          "<input type = 'hidden' id='id_num' value = " + data[i].id_num + " >",
        ];
        dataSet.push(arr);
      }

      var table = $('#my_dataTable').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        paging: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        data: dataSet,
        select: {
          style: 'os',
          selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [
          [0, 'asc']
        ],
        lengthMenu: [
          [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
          [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
        ],
        pageLength: 40,
        columnDefs: [{
          targets: 'no-sort',
          orderable: false
        }]
      });

      $("#my_popup_modal").modal({
        backdrop: "static"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I've added `serverSide: true,`, but it doesn't change anything, and honestly I don't know how to use it. I can't figure out some of the explanations.
My popup html.

```
<div class = "modal" id = "my_popup_modal" role = "dialog">
<div class = "modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" id = "popup_modal">
    <div class = "modal-content modal_block">
        <div class = "modal-header" id = "modal_header_color">
            <div class = "modal_title">User Info</div>
        </div>
        <div class = "modal-body">
            <div class = "table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered nowrap table-hover dataTable no-footer dtr-inline lbl_font_2"
                id = "my_dataTable" role = "grid" aria-describedby = "dataTables_info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role = "row">
                            <th tabindex = "0" class = "center" aria-controls = "dataTables"
                                style = "width: 12%;" rowspan = "1" colspan = "1">Select</th>
                            <th tabindex = "0" class = "sorting center" aria-controls = "dataTables"
                                style="width: 33%;" rowspan = "1" colspan = "1">Date</th>
                            <th tabindex = "0" class = "sorting center" aria-controls = "dataTables"
                                style = "width: 38%;" rowspan = "1" colspan = "1">Name</th>
                            <th tabindex = "0" class = "sorting center" aria-controls = "dataTables"
                                style = "width: 17%;" rowspan = "1" colspan = "1">Place</th>
                            <th tabindex = "0" class = "sorting center" aria-controls = "dataTables"
                                style = "width: 17%;" rowspan = "1" colspan = "1">Something</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <button type = "button" id = "btn_close" class = "btn_close" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "modal-footer" id = "modal_footer_color"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds more like a weight of data problem than a datatable one. I'd suggest implementing server-side filtering and paging instead of dumping > 1000 records to the UI

Comment: I don't think <100000 should be much of a problem depending on what kind of elements you are putting into the data. If it's all just text, it should be fine. Can I see the HTML?

Comment: This fiddle uses the jsfiddle json echo for 1470 array's of data. http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/9802/

As I said before. If you give me your HTML, I can test some stuff out for you.